# Extract column names from SHOW CREATE TABLE

Tags: php, mysql

I am using

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($conx, "SHOW CREATE TABLE $table"));
```

in a loop to grab my schema data, that works fine.
I also need put the column names in an array.
Is there a way to pull them from that $row array?
Or do I need to run a separate SHOW COLUMNS to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the create table result whic will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `TableName` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

You could create a regex that looks for "`[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*`" and besides the first match, they will be column names.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `information_schema`?

```
"SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table'"
```